# Use AJAX update center pane. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null (repeated 2 times)

Tags: ajax

Thanks so much for the responses. I updated the code with following. I am using the Dojo dataGrid to render the data.  It still has not worked for me. yet.

Here is the code.  And Google debugger showed an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null (repeated 2 times)." error right after  this line "element.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;"

```
function UpdateCenterPane(dest) {
    var setHtml = function(element, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                element.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhr.timeout = 10000;
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send();
    };
    setHtml(dojo.byId('centerPane'),dest);
}   

I set up breakpoints to step through the code. I found this if block of code was skipped.  xhr.readyState returns 0 and xhr.status=0.
```

Comment: Please add  `console.log(dojo.byId('centerPane'))` to check the element exists before calling setHtml.

Comment: I am all set with this question. Thanks so much!